# Django AttributeError " " object has no attribute " "

Tags: python, django, cs50

I'm working on CS50w network on the followings/followers feature. I am stuck on counting the followers:

This is my model:

```
class Following(models.Model):
    """Tracks the following of a user"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followings = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="followers")
```

Using the code below, I can successfully get the followings count:

```
user = Following.objects.get(user=user_instance)
followings = user.followings.count()
```

However, I can't get the followers, this is what I tried:

```
user = Following.objects.get(user=user_instance)
followers = user.followers.count()
```

It is worth mentioning that if I passed the `user` and tried to get the `followers', I get it successfully using:

```
{{user.followers.count}}
```

However, I can't use this method since I need to handle corner cases in the backend.

---

I tried another method, however another problem arises. I tried to pass the `user` to the HTMl. However if the `user` lacks the `followings` or `followers`. I couldn't handle the situation correctly.

Here is my code to get a better idea:

```
try:
    # Gets the profile 
    profile = Following.objects.get(user=user_instance)

except Following.DoesNotExist:
    followings = 0             # I know these are wrong, but IDK what to do
    followers = 0
```

I could use `{{profile.followings.count}}` & `{{profile.followers.count}}` to obtain them.

What if there isn't followers or followings in the first place?

> local variable 'profile' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that

Here it's not user object but Following model instance, that is why it's working.

```
user = Following.objects.get(user=user_instance)
followings = user.followings.count()
```

Here you writing user, but it's still Following model instance

```
# that is wrong
user = Following.objects.get(user=user_instance)
followers = user.followers.count()
```

You need to get user instance first with

```
user = User.objects.get(...)
followers = user.followers.count()
```

Or you can do like, but it doesn't make sense as you can get followers right from following instance, but just to show how would your approach work:

```
following_instance = Following.objects.get(user=user_instance)
user = following_instance.user
followers = user.followers.count()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to get it right. However, I still didn't understand why getting the followers from the `Following` object didn't work. May you clarify?

Comment: In order to get it from Following you need do: `following_instance= Following.objects.get(user=user_instance)` and then 
`followings = following_instance.followings.count()` <- this how you can get followers from Following object.